# Why my router does not send the props data?

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-props

I try to build a simple blog listing page with blog cards. The cards include link to the individual blog post. Once clicked, the page opens, but I fail to get the props to display the content of that specific blog.

Here are my Routes in `App.jsx`:

```
  <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<Home/>} />
      <Route path='/paslaugos' element={<Services/>} />
      <Route path='/privatumo-politika' element={<PrivacyPolicy/>} />
      <Route path='/blogs' element={<BlogList/>}/>
      <Route path='/blogs/*' element={<BlogPage/>}/>
      <Route path='*' element={<NotFound/>} />
  </Routes>
```

Here is the individual card:

```
<>
    <div className="blog-card">
        <img src={blog.thumbnail.url}
        alt={blog.alt} />
        <div className="blogCardTxt pentagon">
            <h3>{blog.title}</h3>
            <p>{blog.excerpt}</p>
            <Link to={`/blogs/${blog.slug}`}>Read</Link>
        </div>
    </div>
    <Routes>
        <Route path={`/blogs/${blog.slug}`} element={<BlogPage title={blog.title} />} />
    </Routes>
</>
```

And here is the blog page:

```
const BlogPage = ({title}) => {

    return (
        <>
            <h1>Blog page loaded</h1>
            {
                title ?
                <p>{title}</p>:
                <p>Loading</p>
            }
        
        </>
    )
}
```

I have tried watching multiple tutorials, ChatGPT and all kinds of stuff. I just stuck.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the preferred way to do it. Instead follow this approach:

**1)** Add the route like this (put it in `App.jsx` and remove it from the individual card code):

```
<Route path="/blogs/:slug" element={<BlogPage />} />
```

**2)** Change your **BlogPage** component accordingly using the hook `useParams`

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const BlogPage = () => {
  const { slug } = useParams();
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Blog page loaded</h1>
      {slug ? <p>{slug}</p> : <p>Loading</p>}
    </>
  );
};
```

For more info regarding URL parameters with React Router, check [this](https://ui.dev/react-router-url-parameters)